# SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I can't seem to get this piece of code to work. I am trying to load some csv into my MySQL database. The time stamp is in string format, I am trying to save it as a time stamp.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/tmp/test1.csv'
INTO TABLE eurusdtrue16
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(str_to_date('20151110 12:07:43.786','%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s.%f'),
 1.001, 1.002);
```

It shows error

> Syntax error: missing closing parenthesis

Comment: What is the purpose of the `str_to_date` call in this context?

Comment: to save the the string time stamp as a real time stamp in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is

```
(str_to_date('20151110 12:07:43.786','%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s.%f'),
^  this parenthesis does not have a match.
```

---

I doubt this will work, but it is worth trying giving fixed field lengths:

```
'20151110 12:07:43.786','%4Y%2m%2d %H:%i:%s.%f'
```

Probably, since there is no date portion delimiter, you'll have to break it down using substr():

```
substr('20151110', 0, 4) +  ' '  +
substr('20151110', 4, 2) +  ' '  +
substr('20151110', 6, 2) +
' 12:07:43.786','%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s.%f'
```